# Ursina not applying shader and light to entity

Tags: textures, lighting, python, shadows, ursina-engine

I'm making a terrain-based game in Ursina. I finished making the terrain and the texture, and all of them run well, but Ursina is having problems with the lights and the shaders.

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.shaders import lit_with_shadows_shader as lwss
app = Ursina()
window.borderless = False
t = Entity(model="Terrain.obj",texture="Terrain.png",collider="mesh",shader=lwss); t.texture.filtering = "mipmap"
p = EditorCamera()
l = Light(shadows=True,position=(1000,256,0))
app.run()
```

I tried all types of `Light()` (`PointLight()`, `SpotLight()`, etc.) and also adding the Light class into a list and multiplying it with 100, but none of them worked. What am I doing wrong? I want the terrain to have shadows and have (nearly) realistic lighting (parts on sides not hit by the light rays should be darker)

Note: The texture works, it looks like one color just because I screenshotted from big distance.

[image: Terrain]